Impedance for a guitar pedal into an Electrosmith Daisy Seed ADC
I'd like to be sure I can feed my guitar pedal signal into my Daisy Seed ADC to then work on it with digital signal processing algorithms.
Here is what I know about my problem:

It seems guitar pedals mostly follow the same pattern: Input Impedance is 1MOhm, and Output impedance is 10khm, though some pedals have only 2kOhm output, and the BOSS DS-1 shocked me because it advertises 470Ohm input (what the hell) and 1kOhm output
The Daisy Seed Datasheet gives an example of a stereo ADC connection and writes "Input impedance: typically 30kOhm" so I guess the input impedance is that
It seems to be that chaining guitar pedals should follow a high input/low output impedance pattern
A voltage follower op-amp circuit can provide a very low output impedance to whatever is connected behind it
As it is, the input impedance of my Daisy Seed is 3 times bigger at least than the output impedance of most of my guitar pedals

Here is what I did to try to find out the answer for myself:

Look on YouTube for info regarding how impedance of devices should be adjusted
Get the book "The Art of Electronics" and try to read chapter one and look for sections of the book that might answer my question
Read some existing threads here

And here is what is still eluding me:

Is 3 times higher impedance enough? According to the first existing thread I read, minimum should be 10
Is an op-amp follower circuit the solution? Is it overkill? Do I need to take special consideration when choosing the op-amp?
Should I just put resistors in series with the Daisy seed and call it a day? What are the possible downsides?


Post Scriptum: After posting this question I googled some more and found this interesting guitar article https://www.muzique.com/lab/buffers.htm

This video from Sweetwater selling guitar gear says there should be a ratio 10 between output and input impedance https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Ruc4SoGgNw&ab_channel=Sweetwater

please do not comment on your own question ... click the edit button and update the question instead

If online schematics of BS-1 are to believed the 470 ohm input impedance figure is a typo. Looks like several hundred kohm.

470 ohm input is for sure a typo, they mean 470k. COnnect a guitar to a 470 ohm load, you would have no signal at all.

Here is a quick summary - all you need to know (from someone who has designed and marketed guitar pedals).

in general at audio frequency, we feed a low impedance into a high impedance. A ratio of 1:10 or more is fine. So (for instance) microphones have a nominal output impedance of 200R and mic amps have more or less 2k input. Line level stuff (i.e. analog mixers) are typically 50-100R out, 10k in.
historically, guitar electronics consist of a pickup coil, impedance varies but is on the high side - you could say 10k typical. Guitar amps were originally valve, the input resistance of the first stage was extremely high, most manufacturers added a resistor of about 1M to set the impedance.
These days a resistance of about 470k is common input impedance for pedals, sometimes up to 1M. It doesn't matter too much as long as it is in this range. It also doesn't do any harm to have a lower output resistance of (say) 100R, as it makes it possible to connect to a line input if wanted. In general, it is just a bit more tolerant of different loads.
An opamp follower (or non-inverting amp) with a 1M resistor to ground and a series cap to block DC will work very well. A FET opamp like TL07x is perfect.


Hello, thank you very much for answering ! Raonoke gave some more info regarding the microcontroller, so it's worth taking a look. Your answer though helped specifically with the guitar stuff. Based on your answer, Sweetwater videos on Youtube and other threads here, a 1:10 impedance ration seems highly recommended, and I'll achieve that with the TL07x you recommended and the follower circuit found in this link:
muzique.com/lab/buffers.htm
It features the capacitor you mentioned and also the 1MOhm resistor.

glad it helped! good luck. With TL072/4 be careful about the supply voltages. They typically want at least +/8V as they don't get that close to the supply rails. If you are working with +3.3V only you definitely want something else. But any low noise FET type should be OK.

Hi @danmcb ! Sorry to bother you again but I found the TL072 was what I needed, I think it has 2 opamps built in and I can make 2 unity buffers out of it. I'm looking to give it +/-9V power for Vcc and Vee, and I'm wondering about current draw. I found the Murata MEA1D1209SC dual DC output converter, but it says it has a maximum of 56mA output. Is that an issue ?

@Arno should be fine - 56mA is a TON of current for this. But watch out for noise on the supplies if it is DC/DC.

Thank you ! I'm also thinking about using a simple +9V and ground for Vcc and Vee, and biasing the input as demonstrated in this reference https://www.muzique.com/lab/buffers.htm I really wonder what's best. I guess the capacitor on the output side is to remove the DC bias when going into the Daisy Seed. I'll try things out. Is there somewhere I can update my progress if some other beginner is interested ?


and the BOSS DS-1 shocked me because it advertises 470Ohm input (what the hell) and 1kOhm output

On the DS-1 website it states 1M input and 1k output impedance. Minimum recommended load is 10k.

Is 3 times higher impedance enough? According to the first existing thread I read, minimum should be 10

There is a minor attenuation (2.5dB) with (worst case) 10k output and the 30k input impedance from the Daisy Seed ADC. Nothing to be concerned about.

Is an op-amp follower circuit the solution? Is it overkill? Do I need to take special consideration when choosing the op-amp?

Imho, there is no need for a buffer stage. In the latest revision the PCM3060 is used as codec. The ADC input impedance is typ. 10k and as I don't have the board schematic and don't see any (analog) buffer stage circuitry on the board I don't know if the 30k spec from the datasheet is correct.

Should I just put resistors in series with the Daisy seed and call it a day? What are the possible downsides?

No. Try going without resistors as this would give you additional attenuation/noise.

Example:
BOSS DS-1
Output impedance: 1k
Nominal in-/output level: -20dbu (77.5mV RMS)
Daisy Seed (PCM3060 Codec)
Input impedance: 10k
Input level: max. 3.3Vpp (1.17V RMS  or +3.5dBu)
As the input impedance of the ADC is 10x the output impedance of the pedal, there is no noteworthy attenuation. With a nominal signal output level of only 77.5mV from the pedal you have a lot of headroom up to the full scale input of the ADC. Even if the pedal would suddenly put out 10 times it's nominal signal level there is no danger of overdriving the ADC.
If you rather want to use the full dynamic range of the ADC consider a small preamp (up to 20dB). The exact gain needed depends on the peak output voltage of the pedal in question.

Hello ! Thank you very much for answering. So to sum up your answer: the ADC input impedance is typically 10khm, and so is the output of my pedal. Also you said there is no need for a buffer stage. Would that mean I can just hook up my guitar pedal to the Daisy Seed ADC and that equal output and input impedances is fine ?

Hello again ! Sorry for bothering you again, but as I'm not sure what to do yet based on your different answers regarding expected ADC input impedance and a voltage follower not being necessary, I'd be very grateful for a little clarification. Thank you very much !

With 10k output form the pedal and 10k input impedance from the ADC you get 6dB attenuation. If that is acceptable depends on the output signal level of the pedal (typ. -20dBu) and the max. input level of the ADC. I added an example to my answer to make that more clear.

Thank you very much for clarifying ! I don't know how things work here, I wanted to tick both your answer and danmcb's because they are complementary. Ultimately I think danmcb answered my question though specifically with regards to guitar, so I picked his answer.
